# Centering a target column in the page

Tags: tables, center

The table below will be centered between the second and third columns.

Can I center this table in the second column?  (i.e., center at blue line)

Thanks!

Note: Only consider the column to be centered, please omit the caption

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
         Abc & ~~ & Abc & Abc \\
         efg & ~~ & efg & efg \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if you use `\hspace*{...}\begin{tabular}`  you can adjust `...` to be any length you want to visually offset the table

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a automatic solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \CenterColumn { m }
  {
    \cs_if_exist:cT { NiceMatrixSpace _ \NiceMatrixLastEnv }
      { \skip_horizontal:n { \use:c { NiceMatrixSpace _ \NiceMatrixLastEnv } } }
    \pgfpicture
    \pgfrememberpicturepositiononpagetrue
    \pgfextractx \l_tmpa_dim
      { 
        \pgfpointdiff
          {
            \pgfpointadd
              { \pgfpointanchor { nm - \NiceMatrixLastEnv - 1 } { center } }
              { \pgfpointanchor { nm - \NiceMatrixLastEnv - last } { center } }
          }
          { 
            \pgfpointadd
              { \pgfpointanchor { nm - \NiceMatrixLastEnv - #1 } { center } }
              { \pgfpointanchor { nm - \NiceMatrixLastEnv - \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } } { center } }
          }
      }
    \iow_now:cx { @mainaux }
      {
        \exp_not:N \expandafter 
        \gdef 
        \exp_not:N \csname NiceMatrixSpace _ \NiceMatrixLastEnv \exp_not:N \endcsname 
          { \dim_use:N \l_tmpa_dim }
      }
    \endpgfpicture
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
         Abc & ~~ & Abc & Abc \\
         efg & ~~ & efg & efg \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \CenterColumn{2}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}
         Abc & ~~ & Abc & Abc & extra \\
         efg & ~~ & efg & efg & something \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \CenterColumn{2}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}
         extra     & Abc & ~~ & Abc & Abc \\
         something & efg & ~~ & efg & efg \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \CenterColumn{3}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because informations are written on the `aux` file).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it raises some error: Package pgf Error: No shape named `nm-1-1' is known.

Comment: @Zi-YuanLiu: Maybe you have not the latest version of `nicematrix`. If you use Overleaf, consider that Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: Thank you for your reply!